# How do we get $ ds=\sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{da}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{dz}{da}\right)^2}\, da $?

Tags: calculus

At a cycloid problem I found a formula that I don't understand it logically:

$(1)$  $ ds=\sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{da}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{dz}{da}\right)^2}\, da  ,$  where $z$ is the height of the cycloid.

My question: Where does formula $(1)$ come from?

Comment: This "formula" is just a definition of a curve length segment. It's Pythagoras' theorem for an infinitesimally short piece.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do just with the particular case of cycloid you are considering  but holds good for *all* curves with differential length  components $ dx, dz $ making up arc $ ds. $

Pythagoras thm holds good not only for big length segments but also for infinitesimals:
 $ ds=\sqrt{(dx^ 2 + dz^ 2) }.  $